# C preprocessor macro for returning a vector list from vec[0] to vec[n-1]

Tags: c++

I want to implement like this

```cpp
#define XX ???

...

std::vector<int> vec;

Func(XX(vec));  --> Func(vec[0], vec[1], ... vec[n-1]);
```

I don't have any idea how to do this.

Very thanks if you can help me.

Comment: how exactly do you envision this to work? If the size of `vec` is not known at compile time, how is the compiler supposed to generate the correct code to push that number of arguments? Likewise, how do you envision `Func` to take an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) that can be solved better with the built-in variable argument list (va_list) infrastructure, but let's wait and see.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.    The preprocessor does not work in such a way.

Comment: Maybe we can XX(vec, N), and Func use varidic template args... ?

Comment: Assuming `n` is the size of the vector, this is impossible. The size of the vector is a runtime variable. It cannot be known at compile-time, contrary to the same pattern with `std::array`. For that, you can have template functions to expand it into a call, with `std::vector`, not so much.

Comment: Why not just write `Func()` so it takes a pair of iterators that represent the begin and one-past-the-end of the vector?   Then it can be called as `Func(vec.begin(), vec.end())` or (same net effect from C++11)  `Func(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec))`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you all

Comment: In C++20 there is always [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) for this. That said if the length is known at compile time you can use [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence), which I can and have done to get rid of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your

> `Func(vec[0], vec[1], ... vec[n-1])`

has a simple problem: if that `n` is not known at *compile time*, how many of those `vec[i],`  should *the compiler* generate? In theory, we could think about runtime compilation or pre-generating all the possibilities and then dispatching over them at runtime, but that's both crazy and crazily useless.

So, if `n` isn't known beforehand, process your `vec[i]`s in a usual manner:

```
constexpr auto Func(auto&& range) { for (auto&& element: range) /* work */; }
int main() { Func(std::vector{1, 2, 3}); }
```

However, if `n` *is* a compile-time constant, you can easily get what you want and that `Func` is even [written for you in the STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
int main() { apply([](auto&&... elements) { /* work */ }, std::array{1, 2, 3}); }
```

And, yes, please try to stay away from `#define`s: they know nothing about `namespace`, `constexpr` and other basic C++ features. Instead, consider sticking to `template` - e.g. that's how `std::apply` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the `n` as a parameter to the macro its possible (though very cludgy) and there are better techniques using templates.

```
Func(XX(n, vec));  --> Func(vec[0], vec[1], ... vec[n-1]);



#define EXTRACT_15(container)      container[14], EXTRACT_14(container)
#define EXTRACT_14(container)      container[13], EXTRACT_13(container)
#define EXTRACT_13(container)      container[12], EXTRACT_12(container)
#define EXTRACT_12(container)      container[11], EXTRACT_11(container)
#define EXTRACT_11(container)      container[10], EXTRACT_10(container)
#define EXTRACT_10(container)      container[9], EXTRACT_9(container)
#define EXTRACT_9(container)      container[8], EXTRACT_8(container)
#define EXTRACT_8(container)      container[7], EXTRACT_7(container)
#define EXTRACT_7(container)      container[6], EXTRACT_6(container)
#define EXTRACT_6(container)      container[5], EXTRACT_5(container)
#define EXTRACT_5(container)      container[4], EXTRACT_4(container)
#define EXTRACT_4(container)      container[3], EXTRACT_3(container)
#define EXTRACT_3(container)      container[2], EXTRACT_2(container)
#define EXTRACT_2(container)      container[1], EXTRACT_1(container)
#define EXTRACT_1(container)      container[0]
#define EXTRACT_0(container)

#define EXTRACT(size, container)   EXTRACT_ ## size(container)
#define XX(size, container)        EXTRACT(size, container)
```

I just noticed that I got that the wrong way around and the `EXTRACT_<N>` list the parameters the wrong way around. Which just shows how clunky this is (as it is too much work to fix).